# <c:if> test="" in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, primefaces

I'm using primefaces and jstl to loop a datatable.I have a List in backing bean for the columns.

```
private List<String> visableCols;
public initCols(){
    visableCols.add("andOr");
    visableCols.add("operator");
    ......
}
// getter & setter
```

In the xhtml page.

```
<p:comlumns var="col" value="#{theBean.visableCols}" >
<c:if test="#{col == 'andOr'}">
    <!-- do sth here -->
</c:if>
</p:comumns>
```

but I found the c:if always false.I tried to print out the #{col} and compare w/ 'andOr',they are the same value.

Comment: Don't mix JSTL tags (like `<c:if>`) with JSF tags. What is the end result that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSTL c:if inside a JSF h:dataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442380/jstl-cif-inside-a-jsf-hdatatable)

Comment: i tried to use <c:choose><c:when></c:when></c:choose> instead,but still not works.

Comment: Hi,Matt.I'm trying to achieve a datatable, which include some deferent cols. e.g when the column equles 'andOr', there will be a selectOneMenu.

Comment: @machcm.sz: perhaps try to avoid jstl, and make use of <p:outputPanel rendered="#{mybean.someConditionCheck()}" ..> to dynamically render or not render some sections ?

Comment: @Albert Kam: thx, i use a someCheck() function in the backing bean for the same logic,it works. like this: <c:if test="#{theBean.checkAndOr}">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PrimeFaces and you want to dynamically add and remove columns, PrimeFaces provides a specific way of doing that.  You don't need any JSTL tags.  For a good example of how to do it just look at their [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml).  It is pretty involved but fairly clean.

Note:  you use the **p:columns** tag instead of **p:column**.

Comment: @AlanObject Link is broken. Please check