# c:forEach not working on ace:dataTable var

Tags: jsf-2, foreach, datatable, jstl, icefaces

I've some problems.

It seems like JSF doesn't evaluate the entries of my collection.

```
<ace:dataTable id="user" var="entry" value="#{selfServicesArticlesBean.articleForUserList}">

            <c:forEach var="detailCommand" items="#{entry.articleAndNbArticles.listDetailCommandeSelfService}">
                    <ace:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText id="articleText"
                                          value="#{detailCommand.article.nom}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{detailCommand.quantite}" />
                    </ace:column>
            </c:forEach>
```

It never calls the associated `getListDetailCommandeSelfService` method.

Why ?

Comment: So you thought it's possible to render a HTML table with possibly a different amount of columns per row..?

Comment: How can I do it so ? thanks

Comment: See abovelinked duplicate. Your technical problem with c:forEach is by the way answered in http://stackoverflow.com/q/3442380 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12030126