# confusion about <c:if test="">

Tags: jsf, jstl

I'm having trouble with JSP's `<c:if test="">`.  `<c:if test="true">` and `<c:if test="false">` work as expected.  But the following snippet doesn't:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{orderMB.allAdTypes}" var="ad">
  <c:if test="ad.isNotFullPage()">
   <p:column headerText="Type">
     <h:outputText value="#{ad.typeToString}" />
   </p:column>
  </c:if>
   <p:column headerText="Name">
     <h:outputText value="#{ad.name}" />
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I only see one column; `ad.isNotFullPage()` is never called.  I've tried all combinations of `test="#{ad.isNotFullPage()}`, `test="${ad.isNotFullPage()}"`, `test="#{ad.isNotFullPage}` (this last in the hopes that `ad.getIsNotFullPage()` gets called.)

`orderMB` is a @ManagedBean @ViewScoped.  `orderMB.getAllAdTypes()` returns `List<AdType>`.  `AdType` is @Entity @Table(name = "ad_type").

This is running on Glassfish 3.1, JDK 1.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSTL c:if inside a JSF h:dataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442380/jstl-cif-inside-a-jsf-hdatatable) In a nutshell: `#{ad}` is not available at the moment JSTL runs. Use either JSF `rendered` attribute or move `isNotFullPate` to `#{orderMB}`. Think once again, it does not make any sense to be able to show/hide a *whole* column based on a condition of a *single* row. Wouldn't the very same condition apply on *all* rows then? Do it in the backing bean then.

Comment: You are of course right.  I'm writing my example like that so that I can see if `ad.getName()` is called.  In reality, I want to exclude rows that are for full page ads.  But now that you mention it, I might be doing that wrong.