# JSTL c:set dont work

Tags: jsf, jstl

I try:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{menuBean.modelNaglowek}" var="naglowek">
    <h:column>
        <c:set var="naglowek_id" value="#{naglowek.name}" scope="session"/>
        <f:facet name="header">Test</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{naglowek.name}" />
        <h:dataTable value="#{menuBean.modelTemat}" var="temat">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Test</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="${naglowek_id}" />
                <h:outputText value="${temat_id}" />
                <c:if test="#{temat.naglowek.id == naglowek_id}">
                    <h:outputText value="tescik" />
                </c:if>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

But then `naglowek.name` in `c:set` is `null`. When I try:

```
<c:set var="naglowek_id" value="#{2 + 2}" scope="session"/>
```

then everything alright?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSTL c:if inside a JSF h:dataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442380/jstl-cif-inside-a-jsf-hdatatable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any usefull usage of `set` tag here!, the possible null value would be because  `#{naglowek.name}` is really null.
the question is so why don't you print the name directly from the variable and just tying to store in some variable and point it from the variable?

```
<h:outputText value="#{naglowek.name}" />
```