# Manipulate component tree in restore view phase

Tags: jsf, components

For a web application (myfaces 2.2), I need to reduce the component tree to speed up the application. How can I do this?

given:

a composite component that renders input elements due to a backing bean value

```xml
<h:dataTable value="#{myList}" var="myBean">
  <h:column>
    <h:inputText ... rendered="#{myBean.myValue == 1}" />
    <h:selectOneMenu ... rendered="#{myBean.myValue == 2}">...</...>
    <h:inputTextarea ... rendered="#{myBean.myValue == 3}" />
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

problem:

all components appear in component tree, even when their rendered attribute is false

- inputtext
- selectOneMenu
- inputTextarea

Is it possible to forbid JSF to build up the component tree with all three components? The restore view phase doesn't know about content of the apply request values phase, but it would be important to be able to interpret it still before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this behavior, try to use `<c:if>` tag instead of rendered atribute on JSF component

```
<c:if test="#{ myBean.myValue == 1 }">
      <h:inputText .../>
</c:if>
```

don't forget to add namespace definition

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

Comment: due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442380/jstl-cif-inside-a-jsf-hdatatable , myBean.myValue cannot be used in c:if-Tag as this is not known there. I forgot to mention my iteration by a data table encapsulation the given code; this could also be a ui:repeat, but it doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: Then I see no other way than iterating with `<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myBean">` and building table rows manually. You will lose the ease of working with JSF components, but will be able to do what you want to.