# <c:if test= boolean does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

I have a problem with c:if test=boolean. JSF always enters for false, never enters for true. I checked the value, var is sometimes true and sometimes false, in fact I can see this at the row because I use the same value.

I don't understand this, i thought that c:if test receive the same value than outputText but its look like that does not.

```
  <p:dataTable id="table" var="var" value="#{bean.array}">

                <p:column headerText="header">

                <c:if test="#{var.boolean}">
                         <h:outputText value="#{var.item}" style="color: green" />
                                                      <h:outputText value="#{var.item2}" style="color: red" />

                </c:if>

                <c:if test="#{not var.boolean}">
                 <h:outputText value="#{var.item}" style="color: red" />
                                                      <h:outputText value="#{var.item2}" style="color: green" />

                </c:if>



            </p:dataTable>
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: wow this is really confusing due to the naming of your variables

Comment: start reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442380/jstl-cif-doesnt-work-inside-a-jsf-hdatatable it doesn't work, use rendered attribute instead

Comment: Great! I understand the problem, <c:if is JSF1 and execute once in the first moment. The solution is:  
                         <h:outputText value="#{var.item}" rendered="#{bean.showGreen(var.boolean)}" style="color: green" />
                 <h:outputText value="#{var.item}" rendered="#{bean.showRed(var.boolean)}" style="color: red" />